# How can I create many divs on on top of the other using CSS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, I want many(>25) divs to be displayed one on top of the other so that only one can be seen at a time. I have the jQuery UI draggable implemented, so once a div is dragged away, the next div is shown. What CSS do I need to make such a stack of divs? jQuery is also available if required.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

CSS

```
div.square {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px dashed purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

jQuery + jQueryUI

```
var count = 25;

var colors = ['red','green','blue','orange','yellow'];

while(count--) {
    $('<div/>',{className:'square', text:count}).draggable().css({position:'absolute','z-index':count, text:count, backgroundColor:colors[count % 5]})
                                    .appendTo('body');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that for some reason in IE and Safari `.draggable()` overrides the `absolute` positioning with `relative`, so you need to set it back to `absolute` after you made it draggable.

Updated the example above.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9wWA/

Comment: Needs: `innerHTML: count`.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
#relative_container { position: relative; }
#relative_container div { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
#relative_container div.item_1 { z-index: 100; } /* Higher index means its more on top */
```

Comment: This is fine CSS, you should just put the two div-s inside the relative_container.